# Como debo desencriptar contaseña con AES256 y BASE64 Y RijndaelManaged en VisualBasic.Net?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite3, vb, encriptación

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Tengo un inconveniente a solucionar, no puedo desencriptar contraseña encriptada en una tabla de SQLite que fue ingresada junto a otros datos desde formulario FormRegistrarse en el evento btnRegistrarse_Click, hasta ahí todo bien con la funcion Encrypt y getAlgorithm, pero al aplicar para el formulario FormInicioSesion al mostrarse se visualiza bien el email del usuario que ingresó los datos pero la desencriptación de la contraseña controlada con depuración paso a paso por instrucciones después de ejecutar la Decrypt y getAlgorithm me nuestra el valor de encriptacion similar al de lata tabla, pero en la desencriptación me muestra una simbología rara, caracteres no imprimibles dice la AI, probé con 128, 192 y 256 bits, cambié varios formatos de encriptación/desencriptacion y no encuentro el inconveniente, usando una contraseña de prueba similar para ambas funciones, nada. Voy a dejar la estructura de la tabla en SQLite y los procedimientos en VB.Net y las funciones en modulo aparte.------------------------------------------------------------------------------SQLite: '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
" CREATE TABLE TB_Registrarse
(
ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
APLICATION TEXT(50) NOT NULL,
NOMBRES TEXT(50) NOT NULL,
APELLIDOS TEXT(50) NOT NULL,
DIRECCION TEXT(100) NOT NULL,
TELEFONO INT NOT NULL,
EMAIL TEXT(50) NOT NULL,
CONTRASENA TEXT(50) NOT NULL,
REIT_CONTRAS TEXT(50) NOT NULL,
FECHA DATE NOT NULL
); " '-- " CREATE TABLE TB_InicioSesion
(
ID INT IDENTITY,
EMAIL TEXT(50) NOT NULL,
CONTRASENA TEXT(15) NOT NULL,
FECHA DATETIME NOT NULL
); " '--VB.Net: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------" Private Sub btnRegistrarse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegistrarse.Click
    Dim APLICATION As String = Me.cboAplicaciones.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Dim NOMBRES As String = Me.txtNombreUser.Text
    Dim APELLIDOS As String = Me.txtApellidoUser.Text
    Dim DIRECCION As String = Me.txtDomicilioUser.Text
    Dim TELEFONO As Int64 = Val(Me.txtPhoneUser.Text)
    Dim EMAIL As String = Me.txtEmailUser.Text
    Dim CONTRASENA As String = Me.txtPass.Text
    Dim REIT_CONTRAS As String = Me.txtPassword.Text
    Dim FECHA As Date = Date.Now
    Dim oportunidades As Integer = 0
    Dim click As ButtonState = ButtonState.Pushed

    ' Verificar si los TextBox están llenos
    If click = True And oportunidades = 1 And Me.cboAplicaciones.Text = "" Or Me.cboAplicaciones.Text <> "AppESTEMATI" Or Me.txtNombreUser.Text = "" Or Me.txtApellidoUser.Text = "" Or
    Me.txtDomicilioUser.Text = "" Or Me.txtPhoneUser.Text = "" Or Me.txtPass.Text = "" Or Me.txtPassword.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Por favor, complete todos los campos antes de registrar.", "Campos vacíos. 1ra Oportunidad", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        Me.cboAplicaciones.Focus()
    Else
        ' Generar claves y vector de inicialización
        Dim aes As Aes = Aes.Create()
        aes.GenerateKey()
        aes.GenerateIV()

        ' Convertir las claves y el IV a cadenas base64
        Dim keyBase64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(aes.Key)
        Dim ivBase64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(aes.IV)
        ' Clave maestra para encriptar las claves
        Dim masterKey As String = "ThisIsASampleMasterKey1234567890"
        ' Encriptar las claves y el IV antes de guardarlas en My.Settings
        Dim keyEncrypted As String = ModulatingConfiguration.Encrypt(keyBase64, masterKey)
        Dim ivEncrypted As String = ModulatingConfiguration.Encrypt(ivBase64, masterKey)
        Dim masterKeyEncrypted As String = ModulatingConfiguration.Encrypt(masterKey, masterKey)
        ' Guardar las claves encriptadas en My.Settings
        My.Settings.claveAES = keyEncrypted
        My.Settings.vectorAES = ivEncrypted
        My.Settings.masterKey = masterKeyEncrypted
        My.Settings.Save()
        'Desaparecer la clave original
        masterKey = Nothing
        ' Encriptar la contraseña antes de almacenarla en la base de datos
        Dim contrasenaEncriptada As String = ModulatingConfiguration.Encrypt(CONTRASENA, keyEncrypted)
        Dim reitContrasEncriptada As String = ModulatingConfiguration.Encrypt(REIT_CONTRAS, keyEncrypted)
        ' Insertar usuario en la base de datos
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        End If

        Try
            Using transaction As SQLiteTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction()
                Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO TB_Registrarse (APLICATION, NOMBRES, APELLIDOS, DIRECCION, TELEFONO, EMAIL, CONTRASENA, REIT_CONTRAS, FECHA) VALUES (@APLICATION, @NOMBRES, @APELLIDOS, @DIRECCION, @TELEFONO, @EMAIL, @CONTRASENA, @REIT_CONTRAS, @FECHA)"
                Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(query, conn)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APLICATION", APLICATION)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOMBRES", NOMBRES)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APELLIDOS", APELLIDOS)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIRECCION", DIRECCION)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TELEFONO", TELEFONO)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMAIL", EMAIL)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CONTRASENA", contrasenaEncriptada)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REIT_CONTRAS", reitContrasEncriptada)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHA", FECHA)

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    transaction.Commit()

                    MessageBox.Show("Usuario registrado correctamente.", "Registro Exitoso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error al registrar usuario: " & ex.Message, "Error de Registro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End If
    Me.Close()
End Sub " -- VB.Net:InicioSesion -- " Private Sub RetornarEmailUsuario()
    Dim txtPass As TextBox = New TextBox
    Dim lblEmailUser As Label = New Label
    Try
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        End If

        Dim query As String = "SELECT EMAIL, CONTRASENA FROM TB_Registrarse "
        Using command As New SQLiteCommand(query, conn)
            Using lector As SQLiteDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                If lector.Read() Then
                    Dim Email As String = lector("EMAIL").ToString
                    Me.lblEmailUser.Text = Email
                    Dim ContrasenaEncriptada As String = lector("CONTRASENA").ToString
                    Dim masterKey As String = "ThisIsASampleMasterKey1234567890"
                    Dim contrasenaDesencriptada As String = ModulatingConfiguration.Decrypt(ContrasenaEncriptada, masterKey)
                    ' Mostrar la contraseña desencriptada
                    'Console.WriteLine("Contraseña desencriptada: " & contrasenaDesencriptada)

                    ' Comparar la contraseña ingresada con la contraseña desencriptada
                    If txtPass.Text = contrasenaDesencriptada Then
                        'lblEmailUser.Text = emailDesencriptado
                        MessageBox.Show("Contraseña desencriptado: " & contrasenaDesencriptada, "Contraseña Desencriptado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Contraseña incorrecta. No se puede habilitar la aplicación.", "Error de autenticación", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    End If
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub " '-- Modulo con las funciones: -- " Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Module ModulatingConfiguration
    'Public Class Aes256Base64Encrypter(Original)

    Public Function Encrypt(ByVal plainText As String, ByVal masterKey As String) As String
        Dim encryptedPassword As String = Nothing
        Using outputStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
            Dim algorithm As RijndaelManaged = getAlgorithm(masterKey)
            Using cryptoStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(outputStream, algorithm.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                Dim inputBuffer() As Byte = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText)
                cryptoStream.Write(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length)
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
                encryptedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(outputStream.ToArray())
            End Using
        End Using
        Return encryptedPassword
    End Function

    Public Function Decrypt(ByVal encryptedBytes As String, ByVal masterKey As String) As String
        Dim plainText As String = Nothing
        Using inputStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedBytes))
            Dim algorithm As RijndaelManaged = getAlgorithm(masterKey)
            Using cryptoStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(inputStream, algorithm.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                Dim outputBuffer(0 To CType(inputStream.Length - 1, Integer)) As Byte
                Dim readBytes As Integer = cryptoStream.Read(outputBuffer, 0, CType(inputStream.Length, Integer))
                plainText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(outputBuffer, 0, readBytes)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return plainText
    End Function



    Private Function getAlgorithm(ByVal masterKey As String) As RijndaelManaged
        Const salt As String = "put your salt here"
        Const keySize As Integer = 256

        Dim keyBuilder As Rfc2898DeriveBytes = New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(masterKey, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt))
        Dim algorithm As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()
        algorithm.KeySize = keySize
        algorithm.IV = keyBuilder.GetBytes(CType(algorithm.BlockSize / 8, Integer))
        algorithm.Key = keyBuilder.GetBytes(CType(algorithm.KeySize / 8, Integer))
        algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
        Return algorithm
    End Function


End Module
```

" '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------De paso agradezco y comento que en procedimiento  btnRegistrarse_Click tampoco me envía y guarda los datos encriptados a My.Settings, si me muestra los valores en la fila pero no los envia y guarda, si pueden ayudarme con eso, muy agradecido.----------------------------